# In jmeter unable to upload the profile pic in web application which is using "Multipart Streamprovider" and kerberos authentication

Tags: html, asp.net, json, forms, jmeter

I am trying to upload the pic in my web application using the JMeter tool.But I am getting the `501 : not Implemented` error.

After done some surfing I came to know that it is using the **Kerberos authentication**, So configured that too in the `System.properties` file of JMeter. But still, I am getting the same e`rror : 501` .Please, anyone, help me to resolve this .

**Sample Result :**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group_Tester Profile_updated 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-08-28 14:51:26 IST
Load time: 48503
Connect Time: 570
Latency: 48503
Size in bytes: 362
Headers size in bytes: 303
Body size in bytes: 59
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 501
Response message: Not Implemented

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Sun, 28 Aug 2016 09:22:10 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

**Request :**

```
    POST        http://revflexgatewaysit.azurewebsites.net/api/TesterProfile/UploadTesterProfile?Id=69437&UpdateAdminId=0

    POST data:
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hprofileUploadPhoto"

    TestPhoto.jpg
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"

    hammee ham 
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

    hamm1
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="emailId"

    hammee@yopmail.com
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNumber"

    98789990 
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"

    Male
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="occupationStatusName"

    string:2
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="workHoursName"

    string:3
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"

    Cheannai
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="state"

    Tamilnadu
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="countryName"

    76
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postalCodeName"

    600005
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="skypeId"


    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aboutMe"

    hiiiii
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="facebookId"

    https://abc@facebook.com
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="twitterId"

    https://abcd@twitter.com
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="linkedinId"

    https://kfljlj@linkedin.com
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="googlePlusId"

    https://flk@plus.google.com
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="accessToken"

            WooZaoSuVwF5xaNisPbw0xYoofkpTRMRXcc0AYYumP8xi-]a6LPuRpPuDU4sbGibcMRF1dcNREKQqCp    u9a9XllrYntgXOqQFLAvl8w8d85T_2j6jIjp5eZh4XCNxrSOIRs--ttNsqLYuBdGLKIquK8oCy0iyjEPhaUvl79mtLd8Fz91lPnT m8-PIU3E7_00hRpYDN1rx1X8SvlghdA5ZAAiSWZX-YS9iHZ6LYgb09QKPNhaU0gxSYK9L8lH7ksMJOEfNmlPp5kFkj_fQ-EDxyKI NeTRTfjKwCkmcNdfY6mnF36itrD_pxL65y-e5_8sAUlFQ_3UgzfWE9ytibxyvnfMvydZ3aQm4xvUcnhCb_QLgwnW0UYpq8aZw89I JScGZySEd3bT38V5p1ktNoqud9CoTOAfDUlFXxJcFTfipX9_LJelO1masOp4gJcdfcY3N_mcAmR4ixwswCNXRcgTLSZDHBSSTYSF1XMgIGEVpehDSBdDY
--np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileUploadPhoto"filename="Jellyfish.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

    <actual file content, not shown here>
    --np-Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45--


    Cookie Data:
    ARRAffinity=dab3b2a48d5eeba2e398c4272dad09fe1b0f7e17abfbf187e75f241b8f6737e4

    Request Headers:
    Connection: keep-alive
    Referer: http://revflexsit.azurewebsites.net/
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Origin: http://revflexsit.azurewebsites.net
    Organziation: 1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/48.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Authorization: Bearer    x_7zFLPhUrHQwIssBFVvFOlIMlNDpDNBCjohwJG5qjJWQ3zWIAC7cPpnv5f1vH6ZEfIxRS28ui2cD6u5aW8CMZCm1BhhbcaRGxXwmZEBtGIwIANWu7r6RdaIIeIrq6AYNixDo6L4O7tfALHcTLpbiElgbHrKJ3YKbWqNdEXC7fNmI74Aq-  _0D2y1id5plxoTJclOQ5UKFHssMUCh0MWpcRE_lKFM1JqNzlp37wVQUoQjCzXo-  HW_MxNUqF9zgbnf_XPXRKEB1wZpYwbK30hno-  GWD85P3NPknhzCGgkW3rTPsBalULHeSbrGGYIKACNhi8CKtC_8YbwM8RL1UC-fW_tm- e_jqICocs6zwySNzcg7X9BsFe2RrDFielbs41iDSNanAxfFlqdgVhZLOiyR8NxvCLZxrwq2WEvEtdk83scF8LnOTKiCXUFpmkGjGcMOfvOw_s8DtXLugfJBLEyh7Dvc6gyGjGHBmp6eWThs_bb20bmU
    Content-Length: 778351
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=np-  Zxf5w6hXofm0a8SNXC5632tmk_IV45; charset=US-ASCII
    Host: revflexgatewaysit.azurewebsites.net
```

**Response data :**

```
"Error in application. Please contact Revolution IT admin."
```

But Manually the pic uploading is working fine.

Comment: Did you put the path for the file to be uploaded?

Comment: You must use the full path for the image file. If you test locally, make sure you give the full file path, including the filename. I see in your request filename="Jellyfish.jpg".

Comment: I didnt give the full path for that img file .Because i put the file in my jmeter/bin directory itself . Even i tried given the full path but same error is existing.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) sheet

> **501 Not Implemented**
>
> The request method is not supported by the server and cannot be handled. The only methods that servers are required to support (and therefore that must not return this code) are GET and HEAD.

So it might be the case your server expects [HTTP PUT](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) method.

So I would suggest using one of the following methods:

1. Record your request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it is fine for building a request "skeleton", you can apply parametrization and correlation later on
2. Compare the requests which are being sent with a browser and with JMeter using a sniffer tool. The best one is [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/). Amend JMeter configuration so it would be a complete match (apart from dynamic parameters if any)
3. If you still need to build your request manually, check out [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for step-by-step instructions and examples

P.S. looking into `Authorization` header, it seems your server uses OAuth, not Kerberos

Comment: Thank you...you are right it is using OAuth authorization and resolved this isuue too..